# rails creating model with multiple belongs_to, with attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to

My models look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible: :name

    has_many :reviews   
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible: :name

    has_many :reviews   
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible: :comment

    belongs_to :user    
    belongs_to :product
    validates :user_id, :presence => true
    validates :product_id, :presence => true
end
```

I am trying to figure out what the best way is to create a new Review, given that :user_id and :product_id are not attr_accessible. Normally, I would just create the review through the association ( @user.reviews.create ) to set the :user_id automatically, but in this case I am unsure how to also set the product_id.

My understanding is that if I do @user.reviews.create(params), all non attr_accessible params will be ignored.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more it seems that product_id must be attr_accessible in the Review class, since the user will need to select the product being reviewed from a web form.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

`@user.reviews.create(params[:new_review])`

...or similar. You can also use nested attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
  ...
```

See "Nested Attributes Examples" on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html.

Comment: Hi Paul. Can you explain where params[:new_review] is coming from in your first suggestion?

Comment: From a fields_for block, or just a set of hand-coded inputs (i.e. text_field_tag instead of f.text_field). In other words, roll your own review fields. You probably want the nested attributes, though: fields_for + accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would like to implement a many-to-many relationship between a User and Product model, with a Review model serving as a join table to connect the two with an added comment string. This can be accomplished with a has many through association in Rails. Start by reading the [Rails Guides on Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

When setting up your `Review` model, add foreign keys for the `User` and `Product`:

```
rails generate model review user_id:integer product_id:integer
```

And set up your associations as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :products, through: :reviews
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has comment string attribute
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

This will allow you to make calls such as:

```
user.products << Product.first
user.reviews.first.comment = 'My first comment!'
```

Here's how you would create a review:

```
@user = current_user
product = Product.find(params[:id])
@user.reviews.create(product: product)
```

Comment: I don't actually think I need the
"has_many :products, through: :reviews" and "has_many :users, through: :reviews" bits, as I don't need a many-to-many relationship between products and users. I just need a user to be able to review a product, so each review should belong to a user and a product.

Here is the bit of sytax in your response I don't understand though:
@user.reviews.create(product: product)
Will this still populate product_id, even though product_id is not attr_accessible?